# Docker is not working as windows container

Tags: docker

I am using Windows 10 Pro laptop and have following error running Docker as windows container. It works with linux container.
Please can you help me understand what is wrong.

C:\Windows\system32>docker version
Error response from daemon: open \.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified.
Client:
Cloud integration: v1.0.29
Version:           20.10.21
API version:       1.41
Go version:        go1.18.7
Git commit:        baeda1f
Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:08:16 2022
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Context:           default
Experimental:      true

Comment: I have the same issue. Docker desktop v4.14.1. breaks after upgraded to this version.

Comment: I downgraded to 4.13.1. It's working again for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was still the same issue, but with Docker Desktop 4.15.0 I had the same issue. I could solve it by uninstalling Docker Desktop and install it with `backend=windows` again. With this command Dockers Desktop default container will be `windows` but you are possible to use Linux container as well.

```
Start-Process 'Docker Desktop Installer.exe' -Wait "install --backend=windows"
```

I downloaded the Installer here: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/

Comment: Seems to be a different issue, tried this but downgrading to 4.13.1 ended up fixing it for me